# How Do I See My Permission Level on a Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I think I might be Reader or Member, but I can't find any way to see for sure what my permission level is.  What can I click in Sharepoint (2013) to see my own permission level?  When I google this question, I only find info about how to set permission levels for other users (assuming I am a site owner).

Comment: Interesting question; I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a user without enough permissions to find out what rights they have.

Normally you would find it by going to:

“Site Settings” > “Site permissions” > “Check Permissions”

The only other option you have left is basically a process of elimination of the standard SharePoint Permissions. (This could give you a reasonable indication, if they have not created custom permission levels).

Most of the relevant SharePoint permissions are:

•   View Only - Can view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.

•   Read - Can view pages and list items and download documents.

•   Limited Access - Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions.

•   Approve - Can edit and approve pages, list items, and documents.

•   Contribute - Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.

•   Edit - Can add, edit and delete lists; can view, add, update and delete list items and documents.

•   Moderate - Can view, add, update, delete and moderate list items and documents

•   Design - Can view, add, update, delete, approve, and customize.

•   Full Control - Has full control.

Answer (score 1):

There's no OOB way to do that if you don't have access to the check permission page.

That said, if you can code a bit, you can access the effective permission for the current for any securable object using the [SPSecurableObject.EffectiveBasePermissions property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.effectivebasepermissions.aspx).

As a reminder, `SPSecurableObject` is an abstract class, ancestor of `SPWeb`, `SPlist`, `SPFolder` and `SPListItem` classes.

This property will show the actual permissions the current user has.

If you need the get the role (autorisation level), the [SPSecurableObject.AllRolesForCurrentUser property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.allrolesforcurrentuser.aspx) will do the job.

That said, you should know there is [SharePoint dedicated StackExchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).